# Is there a Jmeter listener which supports JSON and HTML visualization?

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter listener can only show raw html response result.
 Any listener can show in graphical way like web browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Jmeter listener can only show raw html response result.

Which one you are speaking about?

---

For the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener you can select way to display response, look into documentation for details:

```
There are several ways to view the response,
selectable by a drop-down box at the bottom of the left hand panel. 
    - HTML 
    - HTML (download resources) 
    - JSON 
    - Regexp Tester 
    - Text 
    - XML
```

including HTML:

> The HTML view attempts to render the response as HTML. The rendered
>   HTML is likely to compare poorly to the view one would get in any web
>   browser; however, it does provide a quick approximation that is
>   helpful for initial result evaluation. No images etc are downloaded.
>   If the HTML (download embedded resources) option is selected, the
>   renderer may download images and style-sheets etc referenced by the
>   HTML.

[image]

---

As well [Save Responses to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) may be useful although it don't renders response but allows to store all the responses as separate files locally.

Comment: too bad rendering takes so long. It's almost unusable, but it's possible, which is what i wanted to know.

Comment: @Aliaksandr, I'm using jmeter 2.13 r1665067, there doesn't seem to be a dropdown box to select HTML display: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hfg2Q.png.   Is there a plugin/setting that we must enable to be able to do this?

Comment: @Pacerier, suppose you simply have to look slightly higher in the listener's settings: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AjzeJ.jpg. No additional configuration required.

Comment: @Aliaksandr, Nice I see it now. Java's UI really has a talent for making clickable controls appear like background images.